# how to load the saved work in jupyter lab running from docker powered by aws EC2Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am creating an EC2Instance and pulling some docker files through user-data script to launch jupyter lab for the first time when instance is created , now i save my work in jupyter lab and stop the EC2Instance and when i restart the instance after some time , i again pull the same files this time through rc.local (run on every boot) and it again launches my jupyter lab but i don't have my old saved files , Also i would like to mention that i am attaching EBS Volumes and once i am doing my work the volume size is getting increased , so how can i fix this issue ?

Script i am using:-

## !/bin/bash

sudo yum -y update
docker login -u  -p 
docker pull latest/jupyter-env
docker run -p 8080:8890 latest/jupyter-env

and this same script i have put in rc.local file and then created image of that in the first time so that it triggers automatically on every boot

Answer (score 1):

You can **mount the host directory** of EC2 machine to your docker container and work in that directory when inside jupyter lab. All the work saved in that directory **will remain intact** even after you restart your EC2 machine or docker container.

Command to mount a directory -

```
-v ~/ ~/mounted-directory
```

Updating your command -

```
sudo yum -y update docker login -u -p docker pull latest/jupyter-env docker run -p 8080:8890 latest/jupyter-env -v ~/ ~/mounted-directory
```

For further reference, you can check [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host)

Answer (score 0):

yes the answer to the solution was similar as answered above by sat,

i logged in to my ec2- machine and created a directory test
and then i went inside the rc.local file and i write the script there so that i can use this in the restart scenario and then i exit and created an ami out of that ec2-instance, and further use that ami-id and load the user-data script ,
my changed script which i used in user-data and rc.local file is:-

## !/bin/bash

sudo yum -y update
docker login -u  -p 
docker pull latest/jupyter-env
docker run -v ~/test/:/home/ -p 8080:8890 latest/jupyter-env